# Tensor product of monoids and arbitrary algebraic structures

Tags: abstract-algebra, category-theory, tensor-products, monoid, universal-property

**Question.** Do you know a specific example which demonstrates that the tensor product of monoids (as defined below) is not associative?

---

Let $C$ be the category of algebraic structures of a fixed type, and let us denote by $|~|$ the underlying functor $C \to \mathsf{Set}$. For $M,N \in C$ we have a functor $\mathrm{BiHom}(M,N;-) : C \to \mathsf{Set}$ which sends an object $K \in C$ to the set of bihomomorphisms $M \times N \to K$, i.e. maps $|M| \times |N| \to |K|$ which are homomorphisms in each variable when the other one is fixed. Then one can show as usual that $\mathrm{BiHom}(M,N;-)$ is representable and call the universal bihomomorphism $M \times N \to M \otimes N$ the **tensor product** of $M,N$. This is a straight forward generalization of the well-known case $C=\mathsf{Mod}(R)$ for a commutative ring $R$.

Actually, this is a special case of a more general tensor product in concrete categories, studied in the paper "Tensor products and bimorphisms", Canad. Math. Bull. 19 (1976) 385-401, by B. Banaschewski and E. Nelson.

Here are some examples: For $C=\mathsf{Set}$, the tensor product equals the usual cartesian product. This is also true for $C=\mathsf{Set}_*$. For $C=\mathsf{Grp}$, we get $G \otimes H \cong G^{\mathsf{ab}} \otimes_{\mathbb{Z}} H^{\mathsf{ab}}$, using the [Eckmann-Hilton argument](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eckmann%E2%80%93Hilton_argument). (This differs from the "tensor product of groups" studied in the literature). The case $C=\mathsf{CMon}$ is very similar to the well-known case $C=\mathsf{Ab}$ and is spelled out [here](http://www.cs.man.ac.uk/~hsimmons/DOCUMENTS/PAPERSandNOTES/TPoCM.pdf); namely, we have internal homs and therefore a hom-tensor-adjunction. The same is true for $C=\mathsf{Mod}(\Lambda)$ for a commutative algebraic monad $\Lambda$, see [here](http://arxiv.org/abs/0704.2030), Section 5.3.

Note that the tensor product is commutative, and that it commutes with *filtered* colimits in each variable. However, the case $C=\mathsf{Grp}$ shows that it does not have to commute with coproducts. In particular, tensoring with some object is no left adjoint. Also, the free object on one generator is not a unit in general:

Let us consider $C=\mathsf{Mon}$. Then, we have

$\mathbb{N} \otimes M = M / \{ (mn)^p = m^p n^p \}_{m,n \in M, p \in \mathbb{N}}$

The usual proof of the associativity of the tensor product breaks down: There is a map $\beta : M \times (N \otimes K) \to (M \otimes N) \otimes K$ mapping $(m, n \otimes k) \mapsto (m \otimes n) \otimes k$, which is a homomorphism in the second variable. But what about the first variable? The equation $\beta(mm',t) = \beta(m,t) \beta(m',t)$ is clear if $t \in N \otimes K$ is a pure tensor. But for $t=(n \otimes k) (n' \otimes k')$ we end up with the unlikely equation

$((m \otimes n) \otimes k) ((m' \otimes n) \otimes k) ((m \otimes n') \otimes k') ((m' \otimes n') \otimes k')$
$=((m \otimes n) \otimes k)  ((m \otimes n') \otimes k') ((m' \otimes n) \otimes k) ((m' \otimes n') \otimes k')$

Comment: Regarding associativity: have you thought about comparing $(M \otimes N) \otimes P$ with the object (which presumably exists) that represents the functor $\operatorname{TriHom}(M,N,P;-)$ (defined in the "obvious" way)?  I usually think of tensor products as being associative due to the existence of an isomorphism with a canonical object $M \otimes N \otimes P$.

Comment: @Manny: There are surjective homomorphisms $M \otimes (N \otimes P) \leftarrow M \otimes N \otimes P \rightarrow (M \otimes N) \otimes P$, but I doubt that they are invertible.

Comment: By the way, the fact that $G \otimes H \cong G^\textrm{ab} \otimes_\mathbb{Z} H^\textrm{ab}$ for groups proves that $\otimes$ has _no_ unit at all – which is much stronger than saying that $\mathbb{Z}$ is not the unit.

Comment: I don't think your description of the tensor product for groups is correct--for instance, in $\mathbb{Z}^2\otimes\mathbb{Z}^2$, why should $(0,1)\otimes (0,1)$ commute with $(1,0)\otimes (1,0)$?

Comment: @EricWofsey: In $G \otimes H$ we may expand $gg' \otimes hh'$ in two ways (either starting with $gg'$ and then do $hh'$, or the other way round). Cancelling $g \otimes h$ on the left and $g' \otimes h'$ on the right (this is possible since these elements are invertible) gives you that $g \otimes h'$ and $g' \otimes h$ commute with each other.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Claim.* The tensor product of monoids is not associative: We have $\mathbb{N} \otimes (\mathbb{N}^2 \otimes \mathbb{N}^2) \not\cong (\mathbb{N} \otimes \mathbb{N}^2) \otimes \mathbb{N}^2$.

First, let us look in general what $\mathbb{N} \otimes -$ does. This was already mentioned without proof by the OP. If $M$ is a monoid and $\langle u \rangle = \mathbb{N}$ is the free monoid with one generator, then $\mathbb{N} \otimes M$ is generated by $\{u \otimes m : m \in M\}$ subject to the relation that $u^p \otimes -$ is a homomorphism for all $p \geq 0$, which means that $u \otimes -$ is a homomorphism and $u \otimes (m_1 m_2)^p = u \otimes m_1^p  m_2^p$ holds for all $m_1,m_2 \in M$. Thus, we have an isomorphism $\mathbb{N} \otimes M \cong M / \bigl((m_1 m_2)^p = m_1^p m_2^p\bigr)$.

*Definition.* Let us call a monoid power-homomorphic if for each each $p \geq 0$ the $p$th power map $m \mapsto m^p$ is a homomorphism. Thus, $\mathbb{N} \otimes M$ is the universal power-homomorphic quotient of $M$. Then $M$ is power-homomorphic iff $M \cong \mathbb{N} \otimes M$ iff the canonical homomorphism $M \to \mathbb{N} \otimes M$ is an isomorphism.

Now let us dismantle the explicit construction of the tensor product of monoids.

*Definition.* Let $M,N$ be two monoids. Let $F$ denote the free monoid on the set $|M| \times |N|$. For $w,w' \in F$ we define $w \sim_1 w'$ when we can write $w$ and $w'$ in one of the following forms:

- $w = A (m,nn') B$ and $w' = A (m,n) (m,n') B$
- $w = A (mm',n) B$ and $w' = A (m,n) (m',n) B$
- $w = A (m,1) B$ and $w' = AB$
- $w = A (1,n) B$ and $w' = A B$

Here, $A,B \in F$, $m,m' \in M$ and $n,n' \in N$.
Let $\sim_2$ denote the symmetric closure of $\sim_1$, so that $w \sim_2 w'$ holds iff $w \sim_1 w'$ or $w' \sim_1 w$. Finally, let $\sim_3$ denote the transitive closure of $\sim_2$, so that $w \sim_3 w'$ holds iff there is a chain $w = w_0 \sim_2 w_1 \sim_2 \dotsc \sim_2 w_n = w'$. Observe that $\sim_3$ is a congruence relation on $F$, in fact the smallest one which makes $(m,n)$ a homomorphism in both variables. Thus, $M \otimes N = F/{\sim_3}$.

*Definition.* Let $M$ be a monoid. We call $m \in M$ strongly irreducible if $m \neq 1$ and if whenever $m = ab$, then $a=1$ or $b=1$.

Basically, I introduce this strong property because I do not want to bother about units.

*Lemma.* Let $M,N$ be two monoids with the property $xy=1 \implies x=y=1$. Let $x_1,\dotsc,x_r \in M$ (resp. $y_1,\dotsc,y_r$) be a sequence of strongly irreducible elements in $M$ (resp. $N$), such that $x_i \neq x_{i+1}$ (resp. $y_i \neq y_{i+1}$) for $1 \leq i < r$. Consider the element $w := (x_1,y_1) \cdots (x_r,y_r)$ in the free monoid $F$ on the set $|M| \times |N|$. Then the $\sim_3$-equivalence class of $w$ consists precisely of those elements of the form $p_0 (x_1,y_1) p_1 \cdots (x_r,y_r) p_r$, where each $p_i$ is a (possibly empty) product of elements of the form $(1,n)$ or $(m,1)$.

Before we give the proof, let us demonstrate how the claim follows:

*Proof of the claim.* Since $\mathbb{N}^2$ is power-homomorphic (even commutative), we have $\mathbb{N} \otimes \mathbb{N}^2 \cong \mathbb{N}^2$. Thus, we need to prove that $\mathbb{N} \otimes (\mathbb{N}^2 \otimes \mathbb{N}^2) \not\cong \mathbb{N}^2 \otimes \mathbb{N}^2$, i.e. that $\mathbb{N}^2 \otimes \mathbb{N}^2$ is not power-homomorphic. We denote the canonical generators of the first tensor factor by $\mathbb{N}^2 = \langle x_1,x_2 : x_2 x_1 = x_1 x_2 \rangle$ and of the second tensor factor by $\mathbb{N}^2 = \langle y_2,y_2 : y_1 y_2 = y_2 y_1 \rangle$. Notice that these generators are strongly irreducible. The Lemma implies that in the free monoid on $\mathbb{N}^2 \times \mathbb{N}^2$ the element $(x_1,y_1) (x_2,y_2) (x_1,y_1) (x_2,y_2)$ is not equivalent to $(x_1,y_1) (x_1,y_1) (x_2,y_2) (x_2,y_2)$. This means that in $\mathbb{N}^2 \otimes \mathbb{N}^2$ we have $((x_1 \otimes y_1) (x_2 \otimes y_2))^2 \neq (x_1 \otimes y_1)^2 (x_2 \otimes y_2)^2$. Thus, $\mathbb{N}^2 \otimes \mathbb{N}^2$ is not power-homomorphic. $\checkmark$

Now we prove the Lemma.

*Proof of the Lemma.* It is clear that every element of the form $p_0 (x_1,y_1) p_1 \cdots (x_r,y_r) p_r$ is $\sim_3$-equivalent to $w$. Conversely, let $w''$ be $\sim_3$-equivalent to $w$. There is a chain of $\sim_2$-equivalences from $w$ to $w''$. By induction on its length, we see that there is some $w' = p_0 (x_1,y_1) p_1 \cdots (x_n,y_n) p_n$ such that $w' \sim_2 w''$. We have 2 cases, each one having 4 subcases:

Case 1: $w' \sim_1 w''$.

Case 1a: $w' = A (m,nn') B$, $w'' = A (m,n) (m,n') B$: Then $(m,nn')$ is either some $(x_i,y_i)$ or one of the pairs $(m,1)$ in some $p_i$, or one of the pairs $(1,n'')$ in some $p_i$. In the first case, we have $n=1$ or $n'=1$ since $y_i$ is strongly irreducible, hence $w'' = A (x_i,1) (x_i,y_i) B$ or $w'' = A (x_i,y_i) (x_i,1) B$. We deduce that $w''$ has the desired form, because it results from $w'$ by adding the factor $(x_i,1)$ somewhere. In the second case, we have $nn'=1$, hence $n=n'=1$, hence $w'' = A(m,1)(m,1)B$ has the desired form, because it results from $w'$ by adding the factor $(m,1)$ somewhere. In the third case, we have $m=1$, hence $w'' = A(1,n) (1,n') B$ has the desired form, because it results $w'$ by expanding $(1,nn')$ in $p_i$ to $(1,n) (1,n')$.

Case 1b: $w' = A (mm',n) B$, $w'' = A (m,n) (m',n) B$: Analogous to 1a.

Case 1c: $w' = A (m,1) B$, $w'' = AB$: Then $(m,1)$ is either some $(x_i,y_i)$, which is not possible since $y_i \neq 1$, or $(m,1)$ is some pair in some $p_i$. Then $w'' = AB$ has the desired form, because it resulsts from $w'$ by removing a factor of $p_i$.

Case 1d: $w' = A (1,n) B$, $w'' = AB$: Analogous to 1c.

Case 2: $w'' \sim_1 w'$.

Case 2a: $w'' = A (m,nn') B$, $w' = A (m,n) (m,n') B$: Then either $(m,n)=(x_i,y_i)$ and hence $(m,n')$ is the first factor of $p_i$, or $(m,n)$ is some factor of some $p_i$ and hence $(m,n')$ is the next factor, or even $(x_{i+1},y_{i+1})$. If the first is true, then $m=x_i$, $n=y_i$ and $n'=1$ (since $m \neq 1$). Then $w'' = A (x_i,y_i) B$ results from $w'$ by removing the first factor of $p_i$, hence has the desired form. If the second is true, and both $(m,n)$, $(m,n')$ are factors of $p_i$, then $m=1$ and hence $(m,nn') = (1,nn')$ is a allowed factor, or $n=1$ and hence $(m,nn') = (m,n')$ is an allowed factor as well. Now if $(m,n')=(x_{i+1},y_{i+1})$, then $m \neq 1$ and thus $n=1$, so that $w'' = A (x_{i+1},y_{i+1}) B$ results from $w'$ by removing the last factor of $p_i$, which thus has the desired form.

Case 2b: $w'' = A (mm',n) B$, $w' = A (m,n) (m',n) B$: Analogous to 2a.

Case 2c: $w'' = A (m,1) B$, $w' = AB$. This means that we insert some $(m,1)$ somewhere in one of the $p_i$ in $w'$, so that $w''$ has the desired form.

Case 2d: $w'' = A (1,n) B$, $w' = AB$: Analogous to 2c.

This finishes the proof. $\checkmark$

Of course, it would be nice to have a better understanding of $\mathbb{N}^2 \otimes \mathbb{N}^2$ which then directly gives the desired inequality of squares, but I wasn't able to find such a proof. Although you can write down a presentation of $\mathbb{N}^2 \otimes \mathbb{N}^2$ with 4 generators and an infinite set of relations, it is not clear a priori how to exclude unexpected relations which might follow from these relations, i.e. it is not clear a priori how to describe the generated congruence relation. But perhaps someone finds a better way.

Answer (score 1):

This does not exactly answer your question, but it should be pointed out that in some situations such as groups, Lie algebras, ... one wants to consider other kinds of tensor products in which the key notion is that of a biderivation. An example of this is the commutator map $[\; ,\; ]: M \times N \to G$ where $M,N$ are normal subgroups of the group $G$. See a [bibliography](http://pages.bangor.ac.uk/~mas010/nonabtens.html)  on this nonabelian tensor product with 120 items.

Comment: This does not address my question, -1.

Comment: I understand your gripe; but sometimes a slightly different question can have more possibilities. Loday and I stumbled on the tensor product I mentioned coming from a different direction, when it embeds in a larger structure called a crossed square, relevant to homotopy theory. So I was hoping you might be interested. Not to worry.

Comment: I am interested, and many others probably too. But this is not the right place to advertise your work. Because it is not related to my question at all.

Comment: Considering the dates and number of authors on my bibliography of the nonabelian tensor product, don't call it "your work". I am of course pleased to have a hand in it.

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT.** This doesn't work: see the comments.

I'm not sure what you're thinking of when you say "usual proof of the associativity", but the one I have in mind doesn't use commutativity.

Define a multihomomorphism of algebras to be a function of finitely many variables that is a homomorphism in each variable separately, and then consider "trihomomorphisms" (terhomomorphisms?) $f : A \times B \times C \to D$. It is clear that we get a unique bihomomorphism $g : A \times (B \otimes C) \to D$ such that $g(a, b \otimes c) = f(a, b, c)$ – just think of $f$ as an $A$-indexed family of bihomomorphisms – and we also have a unique bihomomorphism $h : (A \otimes B) \times C \to D$ such that $h(a \otimes b, c) = f(a, b, c)$. Conversely, any bihomomorphism $A \times (B \otimes C) \to D$ or $(A \otimes B) \times C \to D$ gives rise to a unique trihomomorphism. Thus, we have natural bijections
$$\textrm{Multi}(A \otimes B, C; D) \cong \textrm{Multi}(A, B, C; D) \cong \textrm{Multi}(A, B \otimes C; D)$$
and so the Yoneda lemma implies
$$(A \otimes B) \otimes C \cong A \otimes (B \otimes C)$$
as required. The same argument using "quadrihomomorphisms" (quaterhomomorphisms?) should be enough to verify the hexagon axiom.

It's not so clear to me how to make this argument work in the general setting of strong monads over a symmetric monoidal closed category... but it probably can be done, since Kock [1971] proved it for commutative monads.

As for literature – Borceux mentions it very, very briefly in [*Handbook of categorical algebra*, Vol. 2, §3.10].

Comment: Nicely said!  This is exactly the kind of reasoning I had in mind with my comment above.

Comment: @Zhen Lin: You should check the details more carefully! Namely, why is $g$ a homomorphism in the first variable? Write it down in the case for monoids and you will see a problem.

Comment: Yes, I see the problem now. Hmmm. I'll have to think about this more...

Comment: Borceux only treats the commutative case (which is very similar to the well-known case of modules, see also my remarks about Durov's generalized rings). As for the general case, they claim "But the tensor product optained in this way is often not interesting when the theory is not "commutative enough"" and indicate what happens for groups. Why is the tensor product not interesting when it imposes some sort of commutativity? See also the example $\mathbb{N} \otimes -$ for monoids: it forces the power maps to be homomorphisms.

Comment: @Martin: As you asked for other special cases, I mention that I have used a number of special cases of bimorphisms: cubical sets, $\omega$-groupoids, crossed complexes, chain complexes, simplicial abelian groups. The last 2 cases are  interesting because the 2 categories are equivalent (if chain complexes are $0$ in dim $<0$) but this equivalence does not preserve the usual tensor products. All these are of interest in obtaining monoidal closed structures. If you want detailed references, let me know.