# "Tensor product" $\otimes$ of monoids

Tags: category-theory, tensor-products

Referring to the top answer in this post:
https://mathoverflow.net/questions/19004/is-the-category-commutative-monoids-cartesian-closed

Would it be reasonable to explain what is a tensor product in this context? I only have an introductory level of experience with category theory and have never come across a tensor product (in any sort of context) until reading this. If this is not something that can be explained in concise way, reference to book I can begin learning from to gain the background I should have for understanding would be appreciated.

Comment: See also http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/205871/tensor-product-of-monoids-and-arbitrary-algebraic-structures

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The basic notion here is that of a [monoidal category](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monoidal_category), which is a category $C$ together with a functor $\otimes : C \times C \to C$, the monoidal operation, together with some extra data satisfying some extra properties. Any category with finite products is a monoidal category with $\otimes$ the product functor; these are the [cartesian monoidal categories](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/cartesian+monoidal+category).

But there are many important examples which are not cartesian monoidal, the prototypical one being the category $\text{Vect}$ of vector spaces. $\text{Vect}$ can be made into a monoidal category where the monoidal operation is the [tensor product of vector spaces](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tensor_product#Tensor_product_of_vector_spacest), and this is why sometimes monoidal operations are called tensor products. If you aren't familiar with the tensor product of vector spaces, I strongly recommend becoming comfortable with that special case before trying to understand monoidal categories in general.