# What is the most generic algebraic structure for which we can define a tensor product?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, vector-spaces, modules, tensor-products

We can define a tensor product of two vector spaces. But vector spaces are themselves modules and we can also define a [tensor product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tensor_product) of two modules. My question is the following: are [modules](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Module_%28mathematics%29) the "most generic" algebraic structures for which we can define a tensor product ?

Comment: We can define tensor products for any commutative algebraic theory. This includes $A$-modules for any commutative ring $A$.

Comment: Arguably, for any category that can be given the structure of a monoidal category ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monoidal_category)), its objects "have a tensor product" (namely, the monoidal product). And [any category with finite products can be given the structure of a monoidal category](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monoidal_category#Examples), with the Cartesian product playing the role of the "tensor product". Is that satisfactory?

Comment: @ZevChonoles I am not very fluent in category theory, but is it correct to say that we can always define a tensor product of two monoids?

Comment: Well, yes, but that is not really what I am saying in my comment. What my comment is saying is that for any sort of mathematical object where you can form a product $\times$ (e.g., monoids, topological spaces, sets, etc.), it meets all of the abstract properties you would expect from a "tensor product".

Comment: @ZevChonoles And in set theory (not category theory), what is the most generic mathematical object where we can form a product ?

Comment: @Vincent: That question makes no sense.

Comment: @ZevChonoles I expect tensor products of algebraic structures to have a universal property with respect to bihomomorphisms. This is quite a strong condition.

Comment: The question is answered in the body of [Tensor product of monoids and arbitrary algebraic structures](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/205871/tensor-product-of-monoids-and-arbitrary-algebraic-structures)